# How to display Custom Dialog box on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I want my custom dialog box to load on button click but that's not happening.I am using the dialog box on this webpage.

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#default

here is my code..

```
      function click(){
      $(function() {
           $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
            width : 250,
            height: 180,
            modal : true
            });
            });
           }


     <div>
    <button type="button" id="put" onclick="click()">Insert data</button>
     </div>
```

The above code is not working..Please help...

Comment: $(function() {
   alert("hello"); 
  });

Comment: (this makes sure you have included the jquery js file)

Comment: Check your console. Are you getting errors?

Comment: No i am not getting any errors on my console.The dialog box is getting loaded on page load instead of button click.

Answer (score 6):

It works fine there is [prooflink](http://jsfiddle.net/Tchwk/)
HTML:

```
<div id="dialog">
      <p>THIS IS DIALOG!!!</p>
    </div>

    <button id="opener">Open Dialog</button>
```

And Jquery:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false
    });

    $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
      $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
  });
```

Comment: tried this piece of code..when the page gets loaded all the contents of id dialog are displayed below the button as though the dialog box was never created.

Comment: @Lucy have u tied to see what's happen in console?

Answer (score 0):

The selector is trying to find an element with the id `dialog` but it looks like you don't have one. Try this:

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    function click()
    {
        $('#dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 250,
            height: 180,
            modal : true
        });
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
 <div id="dialog">
       Your dialog message.
    </div>

    <button type="button" id="put" onclick="click()">Insert data</button>
```

Comment: I have included div with id dialog just like in the code given in the hyperlink above but it's still not working.

Comment: You might want to add the code in the `document.ready` handler. I have edited the above.

Comment: Tried the above edited code but it's still not working.The content of the div is getting displayed below the button without any css styling as though the dialog box was never created.

Comment: Try including the link to the CSS file for jquery-ui.

Answer (score 0):

```
function click(){
       $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
        width : 250,
        height: 180,
        modal : true
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using jquery-2.1.0.min.js and jquery.ui-1.10.4.

Here is my full source code:

```
(For the jquery-ui.css link tag, change: href="path_to_your_jquery-ui/themes/base/jquery-ui.css")

(For the jquery script tag, change: src="path_to_your_jquery/jquery-2.1.0.min.js")

(For the jquery-ui script tag, change: src="path_to_your_jquery-ui/ui/jquery-ui.js")

(For your demos.css link tag, change: href="path_to_your_jquery-ui/demos/demos.css")

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="add-ons/jui/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
    <script src="add-ons/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="add-ons/jui/ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="add-ons/jui/demos/demos.css"/>
    <!-- this in-file styling is used to hide the #dialog element initially -->
    <style>
      #dialog {
        display: none;
      }
    </style>
    <script> 
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#put").on("click", function(evnt) {
          $(function() {
            $("#dialog").dialog({
              width:250,
              height: 180,
              modal:true
            });
          });
          evnt.preventDefault();
        });        
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
      <p>
        This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. 
        The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="button" id="put">Insert data</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Be sure to pass an event parameter to your callback function in your 'on click' function and call the preventDefault() method on it. Read more about [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) Also, [here](http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/)'s an good read on event.preventDefault() vs. return false

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 40%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.button11
{
    background: #47bb7c;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom: solid 2px #489368;
    border-left: 0 none;
    border-right: 0 none;
    border-top: 0 none;
    padding: 4px 8px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 13px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Modal Example</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <center>
    <p>Green Card</p>
   <input type="button" class="button11" name="submit" id="submit" value="Print"/>
  <center>
  </div>

</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```