# Open dialog before user leave page js

Tags: javascript

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    openDialog(dialogs.whyNot)
  }
```

I want to open some dialog before user leave page , I've found that I can show some message before leaving a page by making it like this :

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return 'Message'
 }
```

But instead of messages I want to show my own dialog , is it possible to make ?

By my own dialog I mean:

[image]

Comment: Custom dialogs on beforepageunload are not supported, nor should they ever be. A custom dialog could prevent the user from ever leaving a page.

Comment: bad news, but thaks for you answer , appreciate it @terrymorse

Answer (score 0):

You could try `alert`, if all you want is for the user to press OK:

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    window.alert('Message');
 }
```

If you want OK/Cancel buttons, you can use `confirm` (the window prefix can be dropped). Confirm will return `True` if the user clicked OK, `False` if the user clicked Cancel. Here is an example:

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    if(confirm('Message')){ 
       console.log('user clicked ok');
    } else {
       console.log('user clicked cancel');
    }

 }
```

Edit (after question edit):

You will need to do a **modal** popup with **html** and **css**, see here for an example: 
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp

For a **jquery** example see here: 
[How to display Custom Dialog box on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16196376/how-to-display-custom-dialog-box-on-button-click#16196497)

Comment: as I described , I don't want to show custom browser messages , I want to show my own dialog , is it possible , or I can only make it in this way - show some custom browser alreat ?

Comment: OK you will need to do a modal popup with html and css, see here for an example: 
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp 

For a jquery example see here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16196376/how-to-display-custom-dialog-box-on-button-click#16196497

Comment: @terrymorse does this mean that I can't implement what I need ?

Comment: @terrymorse want you or not , you should show this browser default popup, then when user click close on this defauly popup , I can show my custom dialog

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot show anything like a custom dialog when the page starts unloading. You have to use the standard alert box.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    window.alert('Message');
 }
```

Comment: as I desribed , I don'w want defaul browser messages , I want to show some own dialog

Comment: Browsers may ignore `window.alert()`, `window.confirm()`, and `window.prompt()` during 'beforeunload'. Using them is unreliable. The "correct" method is to call `event.preventDefault()`. Deprecated methods: `event.returnValue = ""`, `return ""` [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event)

Comment: @terrymorse, yes , I've found this , but this anyway show me alert ( default browser alert), with 2 choices (close, reload), and then when I ckick on close, then I can open my default (dialog, popup etc) , only this way as I understood

Comment: @AndreyRadkevich `window.alert()` will work on some browsers, but it is nonstandard and will fail on other browsers.